# T-SQL query massive performance difference between using variables & constants

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql, query-performance

All,

I am seeing some really weird behavior when I run a query in terms of performance between using a variable that's value is set at the beginning to actually using the value as a constant in the query.

What I am seeing is that

```
DECLARE @ID BIGINT
SET @ID = 5
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE ID = @ID
```

runs much faster than when I run

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE ID = 5
```

This is obviously a simpler version of the actual query but does anyone know of known issues in SQL Server 2005 the way it parses queries that would explain this behavior. My original query goes from 13 seconds to 8 minutes between the two approaches.

Thanks,
Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure it's that way around?

Normally the parameterised query will be slower because SQL Server doesnp't know in advance what the parameter will be. A constant can be optimised right away.

One thing to note here about datatypes though.. what does this do:

```
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE ID = CAST(5 as bigint)
```

Also, reverse the execution order. We saw something odd the other day and the plans changed when we changed order.

Another way, mask ID to remove "parameter sniffing" affects on the first query. And difference?

```
DECLARE @ID BIGINT
SET @ID = 5
DECLARE @MaskedID BIGINT
SET @MaskedID = @ID
SELECT * FROM tblEmployee WHERE ID = @MaskedID
```

Finally, add OPTION (RECOMPILE) to each query. It means the plan is discarded and not re-used so it compiles differently.

Comment: I tried that and I was thinking maybe that would run faster but its still running slow. The weird thing is that the code actually runs the query in stored procedure across different ids. It runs fine for ids up to 5 but once it gets to id = 6, I am seeing slowdown.

Comment: sounds like... [Parameter sniffing](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Parameter+sniffing)

Comment: Parameter Sniffing was the culprit. It's one of those solutions that does not dissipate the anger/frustration but I'm glad that solved it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the query plans for each?  That's always the first thing I do when I'm trying to analyze a performance issue.

Comment: I checked the query plan & DID notice that they were different. So I ran sp_updatestats before I ran the query and it worked wonderfully. However, I am seeing same performance issues when the stored procedure that runs the query is called through code.

Comment: Maybe update the stats and then recompile the procedure?  I don't know if SQL Server stores the query plan as part of the procedure, or computes it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

If values get cached, you could be drawing an unwarranted conclusion that one approach is faster than another. Is there always this difference?

Comment: Tim, I tried running multiple times between the two approaches and I consistently saw this behavior. It's really weird.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand it's to do with cached query plans.

When you run Select * from A Where B = @C it's one query plan regardless of value of @C. so if you run 10x with different values for @C, it's a single query plan.

When you run:

```
Select * from A Where B = 1 it creates a query plan
Select * from A Where B = 2 creates another
Select * from A Where B = 3 creates another
```

etc.

All this does is eat up memory.

Google query plan caching and literals and I'm sure you turn up detail explanations